# Left-align TikZ pics and issue with TikZ graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, tikz-graphs

I'm trying to put together a more complex drawing from several TikZ pics. I have constructed a minimal example from which the challenges become visible (see below).

After the styles, first the two pics are defined. Then both pics are drawn. Both blocks (the graph and the process) should be left aligned. I found some hints for this at StackExchange and implemented them already. Nevertheless, the two blocks and the corresponding headlines are not left-aligned.

Could it be related to the fact that in the graph the outgoing arrow is drawn above node A? This is the second challenge. According to all instructions and tutorials for TikZ graphs, it should work like this.

Can anyone help me with these two challenges?

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, OT1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzstyle{border} = [line width=0.6mm, gray, solid];
    \tikzstyle{flow} = [line width=0.6mm, cyan, dashed];
    \tikzstyle{sublineText} = [text width=2.5cm, align=center];
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [-Stealth, flow];
    \tikzstyle{headerText} = [font=\large, align=center, rotate=90];

    % Define the data structure block:
    \tikzset{dataStructure/.pic = {
        \graph[nodes={draw, circle}] {
            A[name=A] -> B[name=B];
        };
        
        % Draw the border:
        \node[name=-border, rectangle, draw, border, fit = (A) (B)] {};
    }}

    % Define the process block:
    \tikzset{process/.pic = {
        \begin{scope}[node distance=32mm]
            \node[name=start] {A};
            \node[name=startText, sublineText, below=-2mm of start] {{\tiny{subline}}};
    
            \node[name=b, right=of start] {B};
            \node[name=bText, sublineText, below=-2mm of b] {{\tiny{subline}}};
    
            \node[name=c, right=of b] {C};
            \node[name=cText, sublineText, below=-2mm of c] {{\tiny{subline}}};
    
            \node[name=d, right=of c] {D};
            \node[name=dText, sublineText, below=-2mm of d] {{\tiny{subline}}};
    
            \node[name=e, below=10mm of d] {E};
            \node[name=eText, sublineText, below=-2mm of e] {{\tiny{subline}}};
    
            \node[name=f, below=10mm of b] {F};
            \node[name=fText, sublineText, below=-2mm of f] {{\tiny{subline}}};
    
            \node[name=restart, right=14mm of start] [fill=cyan,circle] {};
        \end{scope}

        % Draw the path (flow):
        \draw[arrow] (start) -- (b);
        \draw[arrow] (f.west) to[bend left=40] (restart.south);
        \draw[flow] (b) -- (c) -- (d) (d.east)
                    to[bend left=90] (e.east) (e) -- (f);

        % Draw the border:
        \node[name=-border, rectangle, draw, border, fit = (start) (startText) (eText)] {};
    }}

    % Draw the data structure block:
    \pic[name=dataStructure, pic type=dataStructure, anchor=west];
    \node[name=dataStructureHeader, headerText, left=of dataStructure-border.west, anchor=south] {Data};

    % Draw the process block:
    \pic[name=process, pic type=process, below=of dataStructure-border, anchor=west];
    \node[name=processHeader, headerText, left=of process-border.west, anchor=south] {Process};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example for the actual rendering]

Comment: I think you could simplify your code quite a bit to make it a real MWE to make it easier for people to work with. I don't know why the graph behaves so weirdly, it shouldn't, but it's reproducible on my end. At least for that part a manual fix would be to do `A -> [shorten <=9] B`.

Comment: Two things: 1. You're using `below=of dataStructure-border` is implicit for `below=of dataStructure-border.south`, i.e. whatever you're placing, the reference will be the south anchor of that reference. (You probably want `below=of dataStructure.north west` for left-aligning.)

Comment: 2. A pic can't be placed with an `anchor` like a node. Specifying `anchor=west` in a `\pic` just gets passed down. And since your first node doesn't use its own `anchor` declaration it uses the one you gave in the `pic` it uses that anchor. And since you don't use any `at` with this node, it defaults to `at (0,0)`. And inside a `pic` the origin referse to the point where the `pic` is located. That means, your `start` node is placed `below=of dataStructure-border.south, anchor=west`, i.e. its `west` anchor lies `node distance` below the south anchor of the first pic.